# Is it possible to create a Quarto website and embed it into a Squarespace page?

Tags: html, r-markdown, squarespace, quarto

I have a Squarespace page and am playing with making websites using Quarto.  When Quarto builds the website, though, the page and media files are distribute through a file structure.  I'm not sure I can preserve the structure and the various HTML and CSS files through the Squarespace interface.

So my questions are: (1) Is it possible to make Quarto export the entire website as a single HTML file, which can be embedded in a Squarespace code block?

Or, (2), is it possible to upload the website to Squarespace, as a whole subdirectory, and host it that way?